# How to hit an endpoint (menu route) with the session intact

Tags: 7, testing, sessions

I'm trying to hit an endpoint which shows different data when logged in/out. I am trying to write a unit test, but can't seem to figure out how to hit the end point with user context. How can I do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
/**
* Tests to make sure logged out users cant access file ajax.
*/
 public function testAccessDeniedLoggedOut() {
 $response = file_get_contents($this->fileAjaxUrl);
 $this->assertTrue(strpos($response, $this->accessDeniedMessage) !== FALSE);
 }

/**
* Tests to make sure a logged user can access file ajax.
*/
public function testAccessAllowedLoggedIn() {
 $form_state = array('uid' => 1);
 user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);

 global $user;
 $response = file_get_contents($this->fileAjaxUrl);
 $response = drupal_http_request($this->fileAjaxUrl);
 $this->assertTrue(strpos($response, $this->accessAllowedMessage) !== FALSE);
}
```

Comment: You need to login, get the session cookie, then pass that along to the subsequent request

Comment: @clive Do you have a good example of how to do that?